# value of `this` inside .filter() method of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

here is the HTML I was working with

```
<ul>
      <li><strong>list</strong> item 1 -
        one strong tag</li>
      <li><strong>list</strong> item <strong>2</strong> -
        two <span>strong tags</span></li>
      <li>list item 3</li>
      <li>list item 4</li>
      <li>list item 5</li>
      <li>list item 6</li>
</ul>
```

and I was modifying it using .filter() method in two ways:

First:

```
$('li').filter( function(foo) {
    console.log(this);
    return foo == 2;
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Second:

```
$('li').filter( function(foo) {
    console.log(this);
    return foo % 3 == 2;
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

In first case, Chrome logged this:
[image]
and in second case this:
[image]

Why does the console display different values of `this` in different cases?

Comment: The difference is not related to the used method. Repeat the first method twice, and you will observe the same behaviour.

Comment: I don't know. You will have to look in the source code to know.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Why does the console display different values of `this` in different cases?"*

It doesn't. Assuming the DOM hasn't changed, it is displaying the same elements both times. The actual values are no different.

The only difference is how they are visually represented. This has no impact on what they actually are.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for teaching me a lot over the time, I decided to (at least) take a break from SO for (at least) 6 months. Thanks! until we meet again... somewhere... Bye.

Comment: @gdoron: Well SO will certainly be poorer for your absence. Best of luck to you!